# Does $a^2P(|X |\ge a )\le EX^2 $ hold when $a<0 $?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

That is, does Chebyshev's inequality hold for when $a $ is negative? I have seen some authors to require that $a $ be positive, but when Reading the proof by Rick Durrett, I cannot see that this is necessary or that it is implicitly assumed. Am I wrong?

---

Suppose $\phi : \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R $, $\phi \ge 0 $, Let $A \in\sigma (\mathbb R ) $ and $i _A = \{\inf \phi (y ): y \in A \} $

Then

$i _A 1 _{X \in A } \le \phi(X)1 _{X \in A }\le \phi (X) $ implies $i _A P(X \in A ) \le E \phi (X)$

Put $\phi (x)=x^2 $ and $A = \{x: |x |\ge a \} $ to get Chebyshev's inequality.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $X$ to be Bernoulli with parameter $0$, i.e. $X=0$ a.s.; and $a = -1$. Then
$$
a^2\Pr[\lvert X\rvert \geq a] = 1, \qquad \mathbb{E}[X^2] = 0
$$

Comment: For the example above, in the proof you'll get $A = (-\infty,\infty)$ and $i_A=0$. The proof goes through, but the conclusion is not what you'd wish.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also see where the proof fails if $a \le 0 $?

Comment: @Alexander: see my comment above.

Comment: What had the conlcusion beeen with negative $a $? Obviously $P (|X |\ge a )$ had been $P(|X |)$, but what more?

Comment: As far as I can tell, $$0\cdot \Pr[X\in\mathbb{R}] \leq \mathbb{E}[X^2]$$

Comment: No, not $a=0 $ but $a<0 $.

Comment: Yes. When $A=\mathbb{R}$ (which happens when $a \leq 0$, for the choice of $A$ above), $i_A = 0$ (as $0\in A$ and $\phi(0)=0$). Thus, $i_A\cdot \Pr[X\in A]$ becomes $0\cdot \Pr[X\in\mathbb{R}]$.

Comment: Thanks! That whas what I needed.